# Can someone explain the working of these two plots?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

`plt.plot(np.c_[np.zeros(5), np.arange(5)].T)` yields this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhUdv.png)

`plt.plot(np.c_[np.zeros(5), np.arange(5)])` yields this: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlszF.png)

I don't quite understand how these are working. 
The shape of the first is `(2, 5)` and the second is `(5, 2)`.

Comment: First array:                                                                                                                
 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]]                                                                                                   
Second array:                                                                                                           
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 2.]
 [0. 3.]
 [0. 4.]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.zeros(5)` creates you an array of size 5 with all values set to zero: `[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]`

`np.arange(5)` creates you an array of size 5 with ascending numbers starting at 0: `[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]`

`np.c_` connects both arrays to a 2d-array: `[[0. 0.][0. 1.][0. 2.][0. 3.][0. 4.]]` This has shape `(5, 2)`. For more information about `np.c_` have a look at the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html?highlight=c_#numpy.c_)

`.T` just transpose the array (flips roes and columns). Hence you get `[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.][0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]]` with shape `(2, 5)`.

Now `plt.plot(...)` with a single 2d array of shape `(m, n)` just plots you `n` lines with `m` data points. You can identify the number of data by the maximal value of the x-axis shown in your plots. Since the count starts with 0, your number of data points is the maximum value on the x-axis +1.

Comment: Okay this answered almost all of my doubts. If I pass a 2D array to plot. For instance plt.plot([0,1 ][0, 2]), does this plot two lines one passing from (0,1) and other from (0,2)? And what is the best way to practise data visualization?

Comment: You need to put an extra pair of brackets around your value pairs and add a `,` in between. But to achieve what you want, you also need to switch the values to `plt.plot([[0, 0], [1, 2]])`. Best read some basic python tutorials. Then learn about NumPy and matplotlib. There are plenty of tutorials on the web.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with numpy (much though). I am just noob in visualization. So working on that along with pandas.

Comment: Try the official tutorials of matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html - If you don't find them helpful, a short internet search should yield a lot of alternatives. If you don't understand something, just ask here on SO ;)